# IIS Rewrite rule does not work in test enviroment

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting

I have a PHP website running in IIS 10 on my laptop (Win 10 Pro).
This website makes use of rewrite rules and those work locally.
The url `mylaptop:8181/login` is nicely rewritten to `mylaptop:8181/index.php?url=login`

I put this website on my test server, which runs IIS 8.5 (Win Server 2012 R2).
My rewrite rule does not work anymore. It rewrites the url `testserver:207/login` to `testserver:207//testserver:207/login`. Obviously something is wrong here.

This is my web.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^index\.php$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^url=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I hope someone can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself. The fact was, that it had nothing to do with IIS at all, just a fault in my configuration file.